Can't define the behaviour of a Mock in Spock
I'm trying to define the behaviour of a Mock in spock but it's not working, i looked to te documentation text and still got it wrong.
This is what my test is doing, if the function isCharge() in the object chicken was actualy returning true the test would be passing but instead it isn't.
    def "testing the invert "()
    {
        given:
            def chicken = Mock(Chicken)
            def game = Mock(Game);
            def gui = Mock(GUI);
            chicken.isCharge() >> true;
            def action = GUI.Action.INVERT
            def chickenController = new ChickenController(chicken)
        when:

            chickenController.step(game,gui, action)

        then:
            1 * chicken.isCharge()
            1 * chicken.isInverted()
            1 * chicken.setInverted()
            1 * chicken.setCharge(false);
    }

If the code of chickenController is needed pls ask.
